# Passport expired while outside the US

Tags: us-citizens, mexico, passport

My passport expired in early May of this year. My mother and I have lived down in Baja for about four years now so she can write her books. We make trips up to the states but not so many. I actively check my passport expiration date. I got it issued May 2009, and I was 11 at the time. Now I'm 17. Do I require a birth certificate or just my old passport to get it renewed at the consulate?

Answer (score 6):

Because your passport was issued under the age of 16, you will need to apply in person. In order to apply, you'll need to:

1. Find the nearest U.S. Embassy or U.S. Consulate
2. Fill out for DS-11. This must be handed in in-person. You can either fill out by hand or fill it out online and print it. The link to the website is [here](http://travel.state.gov/content/passports/english/passports/new.html#step1) **DO NOT SIGN THIS APPLICATION** . This application must be signed *and* dated at the time of presentation, i.e. at the Consulate. Also, you must provide your Social Security Number at the time of the signing.
3. You must provide evidence of citizenship. This can be any one of the following

   a. Previously issued, undamaged, and fully valid U.S. Passport (5 year for minors or 10 years for adults) (unfortunately, you're a minor so the passport will not work for you).

   ```
   b. Certified U.S. birth certificate (must meet all of the following requirements): 
        i.   issued by the City, County, or State of birth
        ii.  Lists bearer's full name, date of birth, and place of birth
        iii. Lists parent(s) full names
        iv.  Has date filed with registrar's office (must be within one year of birth)
        v.   Has registrar's signature
        vi.  Has embossed, impressed, or multicolored seal of registrar
   ```

   c. Consular Report of Birth Abroad or Certification of Birth

   d. Naturalization Certificate

   e. Certificate of Citizenship
4. You must present a valid form of identification at the Consulate. Any one (1) of the following is valid:

   a. Previously issued, undamaged U.S. passport

   b. Naturalization Certificate

   c. Valid Driver's License

   d. Current Government ID (city, state or federal)

   e. Current Military ID (military and dependents)
5. You need to bring a *photocopy* of each of the forms of ID you bring with you. It must meet these specifications:

   a. Photocopy must be on plain white, 8 1/2 x 11" standard paper stock, showing the front and the back of your ID.

   b. Photocopy must contain images on only one-side of each page submitted.

   c. The paper should be free of other images and/or markings.

   d. The 8 1/2 x 11" paper size cannot be substituted with a larger or smaller size paper, even if the alternative folds down to the 8 1/2 x 11" size.

   e. You may enlarge the image of your ID on the 8 1/2 x 11" page, but you may not decrease the size of the image.
6. Pay the application fees. The fee is $120 for both a book and card. $105 for just a book and $40 for just the card. You **cannot** pay with cash.
7. You need to provide one (1) photo for your application which can be taken prior to application signing. Your photo must meet [these requirements](http://travel.state.gov/content/passports/english/passports/photos/photos.html).

And that's it. That's all you should need to re-apply from outside the U.S.

> Information gathered from [travel.state.gov](http://travel.state.gov/content/passports/english/passports/new.html).

Comment: Would I be able to use my passport as identification if I wait till I turn 18? I cannot get a notarized birth certificate because of my passport being expired.

Comment: @Jackson you can use it as **ID** no matter what. You can't however, use it as evidence of **citizenship**. Yes, when you turn 18, you can use the expired passport as valid evidence of citizenship.

Comment: Ok, thank you very much Milo, I have found some outher sources saying I can, but I am going to try sending an inquiry to the embassy directly to make sure.  Thanks again.

Comment: It's a minor detail, but you'll be contacting the _consulate_, not the _embassy_.  Embassies deal with country-to-country communication, consulates deal with the concerns of their ex-pats in the country and with the issuance of visas to potential visitors.

Comment: @Jackson, Milo: I'm very late to the party here, but a passport is definitely evidence of citizenship at any time.  The restriction on passports issued before age 16 is only that you can't use the "renewal" process on form DS-82 to get a new passport by mail. The previous passport is still accepted as proof of citizenship (the DS-11 instructions say "submit a previous US passport or...").